# JavaScript execute for loop but only see results for last element in array

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-devtools

I'm trying to come up with a js snippet for devtools that will automatically add some information within some input tags.

What I've done:

```
var labels = [
    "navigationStart",
    "unloadEventStart",
    "unloadEventEnd"];

var newRuleXpath = "//div[@class='btn-group dropdown']/button[@class='btn btn-primary']";
var formControlClass = "form-control ng-pristine ng-untouched ng-empty ng-invalid ng-invalid-required";

String.format = function() {
      var s = arguments[0];
      for (var x = 0; x < arguments.length - 1; x++) {       
          var reg = new RegExp("\\{" + x + "\\}", "gm");             
          s = s.replace(reg, arguments[x + 1]);
      }
      return s;
  }


function getElementByXpath(path) {
  return document.evaluate(path, document, null, XPathResult.FIRST_ORDERED_NODE_TYPE, null).singleNodeValue;
}

function wait(ms){
   var start = new Date().getTime();
   var end = start;
   while(end < start + ms) {
     end = new Date().getTime();
  }
}

function addRule(rule) {
        var resource = rule.startsWith("resources");

        if (resource == true){
            var regexp = String.format("<span id='customextraction-{0}'>((?:[0-9]|.)*?)</span>", rule); 
        }

        else {
            var regexp = String.format("<span id='customextraction-perftimings-{0}'>((?:[0-9]|.)*?)</span>", rule); 
        }
        
        getElementByXpath(newRuleXpath).click();

        var elems = document.getElementsByClassName(formControlClass)
    
        elems[0].value = rule
        
        elems[1].value = regexp
}

for (var i = 0; i < labels.length; i++){
    let rule = labels[i]
    addRule(rule)
    wait(500)
}
```

So, the code works fine but it only affects the last element of the labels array.

Any thoughts?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Its not that its only affecting the last element in the array.  its just that its affecting the last element last.  You write

```js
var elems = document.getElementsByClassName(formControlClass)
elems[0].value = rule    
elems[1].value = regexp
```

So every time the loop iterates, it grabs that group of elements, and applies the same elements (the first two, as you've specified getting `[0]` and `[1]`), and applies your rule.  Every iteration of your loop is overwriting the last one, as you're referring the the same DOM nodes every time.

Comment: I'm not seeing where that's happening...I see `getElementByXpath(newRuleXpath).click()`, which is referencing the constant `newRuleXpath`...I'm not too familiar with xpaths, but I don't see where your elements are changing such that `elems` is not the same with every loop...?